# Worried about extent of inflation of Wyeast 4766 package

Tags: fermentation, yeast, yeast-cultures, wyeast

My friend and I were trying to ferment some raspberries using the WYEAST 4766 Cider yeast. Now it's 1 day after we activated the package and it is still only partially inflated.

Should we buy a new one or do you think it is just a slowly growing yeast and it should be fine? Did anybody else have experiences when using this yeast for mead/wine or cider?

thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Wyeast smack packs have a small nutrient pouch inside the main pouch (which contains the yeast slurry). The nutrients will cause the yeast to "wake up" and consume the sugars in the nutrient liquid, causing the swelling. However, this is a function not only of the yeast, but also of the date of manufacture, the viability/vitality of the yeast and the ambient temperature. As you say, though, some yeasts naturally have different activity profiles than others.

You should check the pack date to see how long ago the yeast was manufactured, but in any case you're fine using the packet before it's "fully inflated". For starters, I regularly smack the nutrient packet immediately before I pitch the yeast into my starter wort.

Comment: It's also worth noting that you can make a starter to check the yeast's viability.